# How can we remove first element and spaces between them in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, url, normalization

How can I remove first element and all spaces in this string?

```
url = '1    https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20220109/'
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and someone may be able to see what you did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has solved

```
url = '1    https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20220109/'
print(url)
print(url[1:].strip())

#assign to another variable if need 
new_url = url[1:].strip()

print(new_url)
```